# Change Teradata Answerset be character or fixed-length delimited

Tags: sql, teradata

I've created a query to display the result, and it's working properly. Now, I need to compare the returned records with a target file to verify the data was loaded correctly. The problem I'm having is when I copy the Teradata query results, displayed within the Answerset window, the fields are tab-delimited but the file is delimited by a vertical bar character, '|'.

I've encountered a similar problem in the past when working with verifying target files that use a fixed-length-column scheme, and was wondering if there is an efficient solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Teradata Assistant: Tools -> Options, and then Export/import, you can chose your delimiter there, and you can switch the delimiter to "|"

[image: Delimiter]